# Using both moment and moment tz

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have recently added `moment-timezone` to my project. Now that I've started using it, I notice I have replaced nearly all my

```
import * as moment from "moment"
```

with

```
import * as moment from "moment-timezone"
```

I don't see any reason to keep `moment` around. Is there any limitation I should be aware of before removing it?

Comment: do you use any of moment? we can't tell

Comment: I do, but I was thinking about replacing all my moment by moment-timezone

Comment: does importing moment-timezone give you access to moment functions? I don't think it does - I guess the question is, have you tried?

Comment: yes I did, and it seems so, it's why I want to remove moment :)

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/): "*To use moment-timezone, you will need moment@2.9.0+, moment-timezone.js, and the moment-timezone data.*"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove `moment` as a separate package in your package.json and reference `moment-timezone` whenever you need an instance of the moment object. In fact, if you don't and you're referencing both packages separately, you'll be loading two largely identical versions of moment.

The documentation [referenced by @RobG in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729646/using-both-moment-and-moment-tz#comment86480068_49729646) is correct, it's just that the `moment-timezone` package itself loads `moment` as a dependency.

Comment: IMHO those docs could be more explicit that you only need to directly depend on one or the other, but not both. :)

Comment: I just checked and the size of `moment` npm package (around 5 MB) is greater than `moment-timezone` (around 3 MB). So is it not the case that `moment-timezone` doesn't have lot of other things that `moment` has and probably @ajbeaven what you answered may not be true?

Comment: @utkarsh-k IIRC the two packages are separate, it's just that referencing moment-timezone also loaded moment as a dependency (you can see this in [moment-timezone's package,json file](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/package.json)).

Comment: @ajbeaven oh, so help me out please. I have `moment-timezone` in my project that is injected globally via webpack's `ProvidePlugin` so it is used without import throughout the project like `moment.format()` etc.. Also I checked `moment` is installed in `package.json`. So I guess removing moment from the `package.json` will not do any harm as `moment-timezone` has `moment` already installed internally? 
Also my project is doing everything using `moment-timezone` global import. It possible because `moment-timezone` is facilitating via `moment` package that is it's internal dependency?

Comment: @utkarsh-k Installing moment-timezone also installs moment as it is a dependency. moment-timezone.js augments the existing moment object to add the timezone-specific functionality. I haven't tried injecting moment via the ProvidePlugin, but I expect it would work just the same.